# How to get the abspath of a directory from script's file location

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming my script is in `projects/bananas/script.py` and I know that there is a directory `projects/apples` that exists, how do I get the absolute path of `projects/apples`?

Is there a better method than the hacky method of slicing the last two parts of `os.path.abspath(__file__)` and appending `apples`?

Comment: There are functions to do the slicing & appending your speak of; I don't see what is "hacky" about using them.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the dirname twice then join apples folder

```
import os
fruit = 'apples'
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())), fruit)
print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythons [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which is a pretty pythonic way of handling paths.

Instances of the class `pathlib.Path` use the [slash operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) to create new paths, soin order to get the path to your *apples* directory yo can just divide a `pathlib.Path` object representing the path to your script by `../../apples`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__)
p /= '../../apples'

print(p.resolve())
print(p.exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path(".").resolve())
```